# What’s the word that encompasses both creating something and editing it?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to use a term to covers both creating and editing some entity, say a blog post or a comment in a blog. Which word should I use?

Comment: Raj, the best I can think of is "save", but "modify" can be a good word in cases you cited.

Comment: What's wrong with Create/Edit? Even if there is a term that covers both, it's probably uncommon, and uncommon words sacrifice clarity.

Comment: You would normally just say that you wrote or composed the post.  Is there some reason you need to specifically call attention to the editing process?  That might help us find the right word.

Comment: Because I need to use that as a part of an identifier in programming code. I need it to be as succinct as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb form of [*author*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/author_10) encompasses both creating and editing a work of some kind.

> Jill authored her personal web site using Fireworks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the word ***producing*** (or ***production***) could cover both writing and editing.

*Produce* has these definitions:

> [Used about things that someone makes or designs using a lot of skill or effort](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/produce)
>
> [To create by physical or mental effort](http://www.wordnik.com/words/produce)
>
> [To yield, make or manufacture; to generate.](http://www.wordnik.com/words/produce)

Answer (score 1):

Whereas you are referencing blog posts I would use the phrase *WIP* for *Work In Progress*. That phrase also has a connotation of Superordinating; that is to say it's similar to a Hyponym. Also *Rudimentary* or *Rough-Hewn* or *Unfledged*; there are several others as well, all of which establish that you are in the process of creating and perfecting. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I am used to Drupal world (which calls posts, comments, and users entities) where, when I create an entity, I am immediately asked for the values to give to the fields associated to the entity (e.g. the title, the body, and the timestamp of a post; the title and the body of a comment). *Create* is the term used in that case.