# Word meaning both create and update?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'd like to know if someone has a better word than [*authored* or *produced*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111949/what-s-the-word-that-encompasses-both-creating-something-and-editing-it), for both creating and updating something.

**Context:**
I'm a software developer and I'm trying to think of a clever way to name the function that will initially create an object, and if it's already created, update it.

Comment: _Crupdate_? Someone had the same problem with you and [neologized](http://blackdiamondsandpowerchords.blogspot.ca/2013/08/coding-crupdate.html) _crupdate_ also :)

Comment: The standard terminology in the RDBMS world is "***upsert***".

Comment: Is it weird that I find these really funny? Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: This question is better asked on a relevant tech Q&A or SO.

Comment: Exactly the question I had in mind. I went into the thesaurus after looking at the answers, and came up with these: manage, commit, save, renew, refresh, maintain, secure, store, support, install, keep, store, stash, ... I think I like **save**, because in the context of computers (operating systems, actually), saving a file means both creating one if it doesn't exists, and updating it if it already exists.

Comment: For future reference: in case someone is working with CoreData in iOS: `scratch` seemed like a reasonable choice as all changes are not actually saved but "remembered" in-memory (on a "scratchpad") before explicitly calling `save`.

Comment: @DanBron You should create an answer for upsert. I missed your comment, then read all the answers, and finally came back and saw your comment. Some of the other answers didn't mention it as their main word, so I didn't upvote them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the naming of software artifacts is specifically prohibited on this site.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

"Save" seems perfect for this. As a developer I'd read "SaveRecord" as either inserting or updating the record depending on its preexistence.

Comment: I like it! In the context of computers (operating systems, actually), saving a file means both creating one if it doesn't exists, and updating it if it already exists. A programmer is also a user, so it's very relatable (indeed, we *save* our source code, don't we?).

Comment: "Save" is also nice for some layer where calling the class shouldn't make the distinction as to where it's being saved (Repository for example). Whereas e.g. "persist" or "insert" could imply a database.

Answer (score 17):

In SQL terminology `merge` term is used for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)

This is a synonym of `upsert` (update + insert) which, in my opinion, suits even better, because its meaning is explicit.

Answer (score 12):

Since you stated you're dealing with JavaScript, I'll offer '**assign**' as a handy verb. In most programming languages, you need to declare an object property before assigning it, but in JavaScript the assignment operator ('=') both *updates and creates* properties (when they don't exist).

So if you have your generic object here, and you want to create/update properties of that object using a single function call, you're essentially *assigning* values to the properties of the object. Creation is implied.

```
 myObject.prototype.assignProperties = (property, value) => this.property = value;
```

The only activity carried out in the function is '**assign**' by the **assignment operator**. If the property doesn't exist, it is created.

Source: I'm a software engineer working with JavaScript regularly (FireFox OS applications).

Comment: Thanks! Another really nice solution though I still prefer `set` because it's much shorter, and abbreviating assign would give me, well..`ass`

Comment: I work in Tokyo, so 'assData', 'assProps', 'assTime', etc. would be happily unnoticed ;) A wonderful idea for when morale dips.

Answer (score 8):

I believe it was mentioned in a comment, but `Store` is very applicable.

Moreover, `Store` matches in character count to `Fetch`, which, if you're insane like me, is a quality you value in naming conventions.

```
function store(val: *);

function fetch(key: *);

function erase(key: *); // or purge()
```

Comment: +1 for acknowledging your own insanity, which I share, to be honest.

Comment: Thank you. I also suffer this particular malady. I'm quite sue that if most developers are honest, they would agree that such a naming convention that is both descriptive and equidimensional is the superior choice. May I also offer another verb, exists, which fits the scheme and can be used to determine if the key is present with out fetching it. Perhaps a bit pedantic but sometimes it's costly to return the actual value. And yet two more, forge and alter when errors matter based on prior existence.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes *set* is used in programming to refer to both creating and updating. It can depend on the language - some languages clearly separate the two operations, some do not.

Some languages try to be clear by **not** using a single verb for this. For example, SQL uses the verb `CREATE OR REPLACE` to mean exactly what it says (and what you said).

My suggestion is to check with your language and its users, to see what vocabulary is typically used for this in the particular context.

Comment: Thanks! `set` is a really good option, I'm working with JavaScript, I'll see if anyone else comes up with something different :)

Comment: Just make sure that you can create a JavaScript object using the same operation as you use to update it. If not, then talking about *setting* it is not so appropriate. Typically, with OOP languages (such as JavaScript), the creation of an instance is done one way (e.g. with a constructor), and updating is done another way (e.g. with a setter function).

Comment: @Drew JavaScript is very forgiving when it comes to things like that. You can certainly make 'classes' and instantiate objects and implement constructors, but at times when it suits you to build-as-you-go, creating and setting with the same function is actually quite natural.

Comment: @CotyJohnathanSaxman: Yes.

Answer (score 4):

Within the context of development if you are appling some CRUD changes in one operation I usually opt for "sync" or "synchronize" as a method name.

Answer (score 3):

Key-Value stores often use `put` to create/update and `get` to retrieve.

I'm late to the party but mention it because `save` (the accepted and popular answer) suggests that the thing being created or updated is persisted as well. That might or might not be the case. Often persisting is within transactions and done with `commit`. So if you use `save` to create or update the object it might still not be saved. In fact, usually isn't saved.

Answer (score 1):

**Populate** may be appropriate. When you create or update an object, you typically "populate" the object with new property values.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `upinit` "word" for this. In DB world, there is `upsert` (update or insert). Why not to have update or init?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer and ran into this exact issue as well. It is `upsert` but outside of the context of a database.

`crupdate` makes the most sense, but have not seen it adopted (yet).