# Word meaning created or updated?

Tags: single-word-requests

Similar question: [Word meaning both create and update?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227915/word-meaning-both-create-and-update)

I am searching for a word, that indicates that something was created OR updated. Currently I am going with modified which seems ok but not perfect in case of creation.

As the OP in the linked question I am developer and would like to write a method like updated_created_since(timestamp). Any better ideas than modified?

Comment: As Dan Bron stated in a comment to your linked question "The standard terminology in the RDBMS world is 'upsert'."

Comment: @cobaltduck I am not sure if upsert works. Upsert is already defined as a statement that updates if the entry exists or inserts otherwise. It does update and insert but it's more a statement than a status. Created, Updated, Upserted? Never heard of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just "saved"?  Something is saved when it's created, and it's saved when it's updated.

I'm guessing from context that this relates to objects with a permanent store - your programming language and/or DBMS may have a convention for standard terminology.

Comment: I agree, you have to save both times. But do people understand that it was also updated if you use saved_entries_since? You answer makes sense I am just wondering if everyone would know how to use it. You could misunderstand it as just created -> saved. If there's not other solution I'll take save.

Comment: I can't answer that - "what people will understand" depends on whether the language, etc have conventions for that.  If I'm using timestamps in Ruby on Rails, "created_at" and "updated_at" are 2 timestamps on the DB, but I know that created_at == updated_at for the initial creation & save...